# Purchasing and Using Encephalogram (EEG)

Tags: eeg

I am going to purchase an EEG and conduct a series of studies for my MA work. Unfortunately, I come from an undeveloped country so I never had a chance to learn how to use it.

I have a few questions, please, explain to me like I am five:

1. What are the cheapest / best options for a beginner such as myself to start with?
2. Will I need any other devices/accessories except the EEG machine and a computer?
3. What's the best software to store the data and analyze it?
4. Are there any good how-to books that cover all the important details and nuances that I will require to educate myself?